# Probabilities with multiple chances at success

Tags: probability

Suppose the following situation: there are 2500 tickets entered to win a contest, you possess 5 of those tickets.  There will be a drawing of 250 winning tickets taken one at a time from the 2500 possible tickets and each time the wining ticket will not be replaced back in among the others not drawn but will be set aside.  What is the probability that one of your tickets will be drawn?

Really I'm just curious about how multiple entries into an event in which there are multiple drawings for success can change the probability of success.

Answer (score 1):

The chance you don't win on the first draw is $\frac {2495}{2500}$.  Assuming you lose the first time, the chance you don't win on the second draw is $\frac {2494}{2499}$ and so on.  Multiplying all these, the chance you don't win on any draw is $\frac {2495!2250!}{2245!2500!}$ and the chance you win at least once is $1-\frac {2495!2250!}{2245!2500!}=1-\frac {2250\cdot 2249 \cdot 2248 \cdot 2247 \cdot 2246}{2500\cdot 2499 \cdot 2498 \cdot 2497 \cdot 2496}$

Comment: +1 but personally I would prefer if you used variables instead of numbers here, my brain can't parse this.